# How to set the result language (en) of Google Places API for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32246471/2597566) but nobody answer how to change the language using the Google Places Api for iOS (GMSAutocompleteFilter). I need set by code the lenguaje parameter in order to Google api always return the results in english. I saw in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) that it's an optional parameter called 'language', but I cant find the way to set it in the iOS api (not as url example in the doc).

```
if(aQuery.length>0){
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;
//            filter.accessibilityLanguage = @"en";


    [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:aQuery
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                    handler(nil);
                                    return;
                                }
                                if(results.count>0){
                                NSMutableArray *arrfinal=[NSMutableArray array];
                                for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                                    NSDictionary *aTempDict =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:result.attributedFullText.string,@"description",result.placeID,@"reference", nil];
                                    PlaceObject *placeObj=[[PlaceObject alloc]initWithPlaceName:[aTempDict objectForKey:@"description"]];
                                    placeObj.userInfo=aTempDict;
                                    [arrfinal addObject:placeObj];

                                }
                                    handler(arrfinal);
                                }else{
                                    handler(nil);
                                }
                            }];
}else{
    handler(nil);
}
```

Comment: Here is a workaround of this issue. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246471/can-i-change-the-result-language-of-google-places-api-for-ios/56371056#56371056

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to receive these responses in a different language. See here for the Reverse Geocoding article, with the `language` parameter a few paragraphs down.

You can make an `NSURLRequest` with the appropriate URL and language parameters. The response is in JSON format, so you should be able to handle this change dynamically within your code.

A cleaner way to do it might be to create a separate page that acts as a sort of web service for you. It accepts two parameters: A language code and an address. It loads the API using the language code requested, and reverse geocodes the address, providing the result. Your page would call this web service-like thing twice, once for each language, and then use the results as desired.