# Change city and country in Google Places from RUS language to ENG

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I write and test my app in my phone, in my phone installed RUS language. Also in my app I integrated **Google Places** and with help **Google Places** I want to choose city and country, but if in my phone installed RUS language **Google Places** display city and country in RUS language, but me need to see city and country in ENG language without change phone language to ENG language leaving RUS language.

How I can do it if it's possible?

Comment: Sadly, it's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Here is a workaround of this issue. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246471/can-i-change-the-result-language-of-google-places-api-for-ios/56371056#56371056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself. I have integrated a Bing from Microsoft translator that does the translation in the background and gives me the desired result.

Me it enough to translate only the city and country.